# How to get data from SimpleDialogFragment to a Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, dialogfragment, simpledialog

I have a main class:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener, OnMarkerClickListener {}
```

I have a dialog class:

```
public class PedirTaxiDialog extends SimpleDialogFragment implements
    OnClickListener{}
```

For example: I have FragmentA from which I start SimpleDialogFragment (there are EditText in box).
How to can I get back the value from the EditText to FragmenaA? I try to make many things ... but I have no sucessy. Help me please !!

In my MainFragment class, I show the dialog class:

```
FragmentActivity activity;
activity = (FragmentActivity) getActivity().new PedirTaxiDialog().show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "Salvar Favoritos");
```

I would get the values entered by the user in the dialog class.
How can I in my MainFragment get the return of PedirTaxiDialog?

links of classes:

[PedirTaxiDialog.java](http://www.ararimed.com/PedirTaxiDialog.java)

[MainFragment.java](httP://www.ararimed.com/MainFragment.java)

Comment: the class SimpleDialogFragment extends BaseDialogFragment.

Comment: Are you using `SimpleFragment` library? or is this just a normal "DialogFragment" from support library

Comment: EpicPandaForce, yes I'm using from the lib:  import eu.inmite.android.lib.dialogs.SimpleDialogFragment;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have this code where you're creating your dialog

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity()
                     .getSupportFragmentManager();
             PedirTaxiDialog dialog = PedirTaxiDialog();
             dialog.setTargetFragment(MainFragment.this, "some request tag");
             dialog.show(fm, "Salvar Favoritos");
```

By calling method `setTargetFragment()` you're enabling option to get result from your DialogFragment as you're getting result from activity when you're starting it using `startActivityForResult()`.

So in your DialogFragment when user clicks OK button, in the OnClickListener you have to create intent, put to it as String Extra text user entered, set Result_OK and call `getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), resultCode, yourIntent)` like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("textInput", text);
i.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), resultCode, i);
```

And then in your MainFragment override `onActivityResult()` method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == "some request tag") {
        String text = getStringExtra("textInput);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access your Activity from your Dialog, if you override the onAttach(Activity) method of your DialogFragment.

For example:

```
private MainActivity controller;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    this.controller = (MainActivity) activity;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    this.controller = null;
    super.onDetach();
}
```

Later, you can use the controller object to invoke methods on your Activity.

Your activity can then update the fragment.

Best practice is also to let your activity implement a callback interface, and use this callback interface as class for the controller variable, instead of using the activity class itself.

Comment: More info here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity